# how to make sure windows installation media is not corrupted?

Tags: windows, bootable-media

When making a Windows thumb drive installation media, how do know you there  are no corrupted files? Is there a check sum or something?

Comment: No; There isn't a checksum.  The software used to create the drive normally would verify this.  If the process is successful then isn't corrupt./.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Just wondering because Ubuntu is offering a md5 check sum for making sure the .iso file is ok and when booting it also has a sort of checker and just thought Windows doesn't do that. Also if there any official Microsoft usb tool? I know it was for Windwos 7, I downloaded a windwos .iso file from my school from MSDN AA and I just want to make sure I don't mess up the installation.

Comment: md5 checksums exists for those .ISOs also.  There is a first-party tool that takes a.iso and places it on a flash device but also numerous third-party solutions that do that also.  There are also md5 checksum tools that exist also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct checksums for installers can be found from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx?pv=36%3a350#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=350
Click `details`to see `SHA1`checksums.

To find out checksum of your file you can use for example this tool from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

> The Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier tool is an unsupported command line utility that computes MD5 or SHA1 cryptographic hashes for files.

Comment: That first link leads to an error page.